# Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Assume $m < n$. Then $m \leq n-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, peano-axioms

My question is concerning my proof's validity in the theorem written below. If someone could take a moment and see if there is a flaw in it, I'd appreciate it.

**Lemma.** There are no natural numbers less than $1$.

**Proof.** Assume to the contrary that there are natural numbers less than $1$ and let $S$ consist of these numbers. By assumption, $S \neq \varnothing$ and $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, so by the well ordering principle, the natural number $m = \min{S}$ exists such that

$$ 0 < m < 1$$

If we multiply the above inequality by $m$, we get

$$0 < m^2 < m < 1$$

We see that $m^2$ is a natural number and it is less than $1$, so it belongs to $S$. But $m^2 < m$, which is a contradiction.

Hence, there are no natural numbers less than $1$.

$\blacksquare$

**Theorem.** If $m$ and $n$ are integers with $m < n$, then $m \leq n-1$.

**Proof.** Assume to the contrary that $n-1 < m$. Then

$$n-1 < m < n$$

We observe that the length of this interval $(n-1, n)$ is $1$. If we let

\begin{align} 
\mathcal{l_1} &= |m - n + 1| \\
\mathcal{l_2} &= |n-m| 
\end{align}

which are the lengths of the subintervals $(n-1, m]$ and $(m,n)$.

Then because $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and multiplication, and because $\mathcal{l_1},\mathcal{l_2} > 0$, we see that $\mathcal{l_1}, \mathcal{l_2} \in \mathbb{N}.$

However, $\mathcal{l_1} + \mathcal{l_2} = 1$, so we must have

$$0<\mathcal{l_1} < 1 \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \text{and} \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace 0<\mathcal{l_2} < 1$$

which contradict the above lemma that there are no natural numbers less than $1$.

Therefore, we must have $m \leq n-1$ whenever $m<n$.

$\blacksquare$

**Corollary.** There are no integers between two consecutive integers.

**Edit** I included a revision of my proof for the lemma, thanks to the commentators below.

**Edit 2** I edited the proof to the above lemma to exclude the peano axioms, which is very important to me, since the textbook from which this problem came does not discuss them. The proof is now accessible to anyone beginning elementary number theory.

Comment: In the first argument, why is $m-1$ in $S$?  In particular, why is it a natural number?

Comment: Because $S $ consists of natural numbers less than $1$, and because $m-1 < 1$, it is a natural number in $S $. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire: But $m\in\mathbb{N}$ does not imply $m-1\in\mathbb N$. Thus why do you assume $m-1$ to be natural?

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire -where does it say that the set of natural numbers is closed wrt subtraction by 1?

Comment: Hmm. If $m$ is a natural number, then because $\mathbb {N}$ is closed under addition and multiplication, $m-1$ is natural?

Comment: @stevengregory I see your point. $\mathbb{N}$ is not necessarily closed under subtraction. I'll attempt to amend my proof for the lemma.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire - WOP says that $\mathbb N$ has a minimal element and $1$ is clearly the most likely candidate. I think to go any further, you need to actuall see the definition of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Since $m\ne1$, $m$ is the successor of a natural number. (I assume that the OP's natural numbers start from $1$). So $m-1$ is a natural number.

Comment: @egreg Sure, but that isn't in the proof (and it depends on which axioms the OP is using to define the natural numbers).

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track but might be being a bit circular in definitions.  Is it a given that $s(x) > x$, for example?  (I'm actually not sure.) I'd go through the basic definitions and axioms (and I' avoid all theorems no matter how basic).

Comment: Yeah,... I went to wikipedia to look up peano postulates and the very *first* was 0 is a natural number.  So I need to know *exactly* what your axioms are.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire Your Theorem $$\langle\forall m,n::m<n\Rightarrow m\le n-1\rangle$$ and your Collary $$\langle\forall n:\lnot\langle\exists m::n-1<m<n\rangle\rangle$$ are equivalent, which immediately follows from logic (DeMorgan mainly) and $a\le b\;\equiv\;\lnot(b<a)$. Also both are equivalent to the simpler $$\lnot\langle\exists a::0<a<1\rangle$$ (which can be seen by rewriting to introduce $\;m-n+1\;$ in both inequalities), and that third form probably has a much simpler proof than you gave. (Notation: I'm assuming all variables range over $\;\mathbb Z\;$ in this comment.)